# A logic question based on code language

Tags: contest-math

Source:
Today I gave the NCO(National Cyber Olympiad) exam and this question was there in the logical reasoning section.

The question is as follows:

'In a certain code language, if 'VOLCANO' is written as 'QPCENQX', then how will 'RAINBOW' be written in the same code language?

I have tried solving the question by using alphabetical order, however I didn't arrive at the answer. My theory to the question:

---

VOLCANO=QPCENQX:

1. V-5=Q
2. O+1=P
3. L-9=C
4. C+2=E
5. A+8=N
6. N+3=Q
7. O+9=X

However, using this method in RAINBOW does nor work

I'd be glad if someone helped.

Comment: What is the source of the question? What  have you tried?: Please [edit] the question to tell us.

Comment: It's hard to say something like this has a well defined solution. Such a short sample text.

Comment: This is a ridiculous exam question

Comment: I know right, it is pretty tough

Answer (score 2):

In opposite order : VOLCANO --> ONACLOV --> QPCENQX

O+2=Q , N+2=P , A+2=C , etc

RAINBOW  --> WOBNIAR --> YQD...

Comment: Woah dude, I could have never though of this! Respect _/\_